# Code doesn't show anything println arduino? (On every signle language)

Tags: c, arduino, primes

İ've tried every language to my knowledge: php, javascript and c and ultmately arduino.

Why doesn't this code:

```
int n = 10;
int total = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  while (n < 100) {
    if (n % 2 != 0) {
      if (n % 3 != 0) {
        if (n % 4 != 0) {
          if (n % 5 != 0){
            if (n % 6 != 0) {
              if (n % 7 != 0) {
                if (n % 8 != 0) {
                  if (n % 9 != 0) {
                    total++;
                    n++;
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  Serial.println(total);
}
```

excecute anything?

Comment: `n++` is only ever executed when all the clauses are true. `n = 10` fails the first clause so `n` never gets incremented and you stay in a spin loop. This would be have been fairly obvious if you had indented your code properly.

Comment: What about 11? thats a prime number.

Comment: But `n` never gets set to 11 because it never gets incremented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of where you place your

`n++;`

In your code, it is placed inside the innermost scope.

Since n=10 at the start, n%2!=0 is false, and all the contents within that scope, including n++; is never called. Hence, n is never incremented, since n%2!=0 is repeatedly false. Hence, the code never reaches the printing of total, since it is stuck in the infinite while loop.

One possible correction to the code could be as follows below. And the answer will be 21. However, since you are already using the while loop, you can probably put it in the setup() method, otherwise the Arduino will just keep printing 21 infinitely.

```
int n = 10;
int total = 0;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
 while (n < 100) {
  if (n % 2 != 0) {
   if (n % 3 != 0) {
    if (n % 4 != 0) {
     if (n % 5 != 0){
      if (n % 6 != 0) {
       if (n % 7 != 0) {
        if (n % 8 != 0) {
         if (n % 9 != 0) {
          total++;
         }
        }
       }
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
  n++;
 }
 Serial.println(total);
}
```

**Starting with your Objective / Purpose..**

If you are finding numbers between 10 and 100 that cannot be divided by 2 to 9, a possible way to code could be:

```
int n = 10;
int total = 0;

void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
 while (n < 100) {
  if (n % 2 != 0) {
   if (n % 3 != 0) {
    if (n % 4 != 0) {
     if (n % 5 != 0){
      if (n % 6 != 0) {
       if (n % 7 != 0) {
        if (n % 8 != 0) {
         if (n % 9 != 0) {
          Serial.println(n);
          total++;
         }
        }
       }
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
  n++;
 }
 Serial.print("Total: ");
 Serial.println(total);
}

void loop() {
 //Serial.println(total);
}
```

Personally, I prefer fewer nested IFs

```
int n = 10;
int total = 0;
bool divisible = false;
int i;

void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
 while (n < 100) {
  divisible = false;
  for (i=2; i<=9; i+=1){
    if (n%i==0){
      divisible = true;
    }
  }
  if (divisible == false){
    Serial.println(n);
    total++;
  }
  n++;
 }
 Serial.print("Total: ");
 Serial.println(total);
}

void loop() {
 //Serial.println(total);
}
```

And you would get the output:

> ```
> 11
> 13
> 17
> 19
> 23
> 29
> 31
> 37
> 41
> 43
> 47
> 53
> 59
> 61
> 67
> 71
> 73
> 79
> 83
> 89
> 97
> Total: 21
> ```

Hope it helps.

Comment: try it from 100 to a thousand. İt should give 143 primes, however it gives 206...The reason being that it only counts divisors from 1 to 9. Do you know any way to get around it?

Answer (score 0):

Your code's structure is wrong. You need to increment `n` every time through the loop.

This should work:

```
void loop() {
  while (n < 100) {
    if (n % 2 != 0) {
      if (n % 3 != 0) {
        if (n % 5 != 0){
          if (n % 7 != 0) {
            total++;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    n++; /* Increment needs to be at the base of the loop! */
  }

  Serial.println(total);
}
```